# Returning data which is not found in where clause and didn't update in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, text

In a c# desktop application I am getting this list of data which I am reading by barcode into text file; here is the result;

```
R900, 27674T07, 27438T17, 27736T21, 26609T08,  
R901, 27770T12, 27833T07, 26402T12, 27771T09, 26003T13, 
R902, 26003T14, 26402T11, 26246T17, 
R904, 28055T09, 25356T08, 25825T07, 25556T09,
```

and I am transforming it to update queries;

```
UPDATE TABLE SET NUMBER = R900 WHERE id in ( 27674T07, 27438T17, 27736T21, 26609T08)
UPDATE TABLE SET NUMBER = R901 WHERE id in ( 27770T12, 27833T07, **26402T12**, **27771T09**, 26003T13) 
UPDATE TABLE SET NUMBER = R902 WHERE id in ( 26003T14, **26402T11**, 26246T17) 
UPDATE TABLE SET NUMBER = R904 WHERE id in ( 28055T09, 25356T08, 25825T07, **25556T09**)
```

Finally I am executing this SQL query. But the problem is I don't know which id is not found in  IN clause in database. I need to report back to user which id didn't found with its NUMBER

For example the bold id's are not found in database, and couldn't update. So expected result is:

```
NUMBER     id
R901       26402T12
R901       27771T09
R902       26402T11
R903       25556T09
```

how can I return this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a temp table to store the splitted value into it.

then

```
SELECT temp.number, temp.Id 
FROM #temp temp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE ON temp.id = TABLE.id
WHERE TABLE.id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
declare @mytable as TABLE
    (
      Id nvarchar(20)
    )

UPDATE TABLE SET NUMBER = R900 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id into @mytable
WHERE id in ( 27674T07, 27438T17, 27736T21, 26609T08)

Select * from @mytable
```

`@mytable` will contain updated `Ids` only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really like this answer although I did not use. Thanks a lot for enlightening answer.